# How to redirect multiple old urls to new urls using a 301 redirect via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have recently change some URLs from my website to make it more SEO friendly. I have old urls that I would like to link to new urls. The old urls are no longer available but I would like the old urls to redirect to the new urls.

My current 301 redirect code below is for http:// to https://www, which I need.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

How do I make it so that I can also redirect from old urls to new urls as well. Is it possible with the 301 redirect?

Old url examples: 
www.mywebsite.com/book-stories.html
www.mywebsite.com/book-journals.html

New url examples:
www.mywebsite.com/stories.html
www.mywebsite.com/journals.html

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a handful, static redirections you can do it appending `RewriteRules` just as you are doing:

```
RewriteRule ^book-stories.html$ stories.html [R=301]
RewriteRule ^book-journals.html$ journals.html [R=301]
```

If they all have a fixed pattern, you could exploit that to reduce the amount of rules.

```
RewriteRule ^book-([a-z0-9.-]+).html$ $1.html [R=301]
```

If you have many different rules that you will be updating, you can look into [indexed maps](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm) or even [database-based](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd) RewriteMaps

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question but for some reason it wasn't working for me, It may have been me but I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code and didn't work and to be honest I could have been doing it incorrectly. I did look into it further and tried another 301 redirect

```
Redirect 301 book-stories.html https://www.mywebsite.com/stories.html
Redirect 301 book-journals.html https://www.mywebsite.com/journals.html
```

That worked for me. Hope this helps anyone else who will encounter this issue.